# How to show view conditionally when the keyboard appears swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to show a different view when I tap on the textField and the keyboard appears. I tried using .onReceive modifiers along with keyboardWillHide/ShowNotification properties, but none of those approaches work as expected. Here is the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var text = ""
var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        if //isKeyboardVisible - need to implement {
        {
            Text("Keyboard is shown")
        } else {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                Text("Enter prompts")
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Medium", size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 230)
                
                TextField(text: $text)
                    .frame(height: 120)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                Text("create")
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 0.4 : 1)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can consider using the [`focused` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/focused(_:)) instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@FocusState` property will allow you to track when the keyboard is shown, on the other hand if try this with `IF ELSE` the app will crash due an overlap of animations and the way the if else works in swiftUI. Here is an example that can help you out.

```
  import SwiftUI

struct KeyboardView: View {
    
    @State private var text = ""
    @FocusState private var keyboardShown: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Spacer()
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 16) {
                Text("Enter prompts")
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Medium", size: 18))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .padding(.trailing, 230)
                
                TextField("Enter text", text: $text)
                    .frame(height: 120)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .focused($keyboardShown)
                
                Text("create")
                    .opacity(text.isEmpty ? 0.4 : 1)
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            
            if keyboardShown
            {
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    Text("Keyboard is shown")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            keyboardShown = false
                        }
                }
            }
        }
 }
  }
```

Comment: Yes but if I delete the blue background, the views just overlap, while I need to display only one of them conditionally

Comment: Just put the background white?

Comment: I don't want to change the background at all, I just want to display a different view, text for example

Comment: I just set the opacity of the other view to 0 when the keyboard is shown, and it seem to we working well.